# Write byte to file with x86 assembler

Tags: c, assembly

I want to make a function in assembler to be called from c that will write a byte(char) to the file. Here is how function should look in c:

```
void writebyte (FILE *f, char b)
{
    fwrite(&b, 1, 1, f);
}
```

And here is the code that will call it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void writebyte(FILE *, char);

int main(void) {
    FILE *f  = fopen("test.txt", "w");    
    writebyte(f, 1);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

So far I came up with following assembler code:

```
    .global     writebyte  
writebyte:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp  #standard params
    pushl   12(%ebp)    # pushing byte to the stack
    pushl   $1
    pushl   $1
    pushl   8(%ebp)     #file to write
    call    fwrite
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

I keep getting from gdb:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xffa9702c in ?? ()
```

How do I write such a function in assembly?

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: As you don't have have std library with assembler, then the code will be OS-dependent.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The first parameter in calling fwrite is an address that points to the byte, not the byte itself; assuming that you have linked the program correctly, you are most likely getting a seg fault because fwrite is trying to use your byte as an address, and access memory at addresses that aren't mapped in your virtual address space.

Comment: @MattJordan hmm might be that. How do I send an adress instead of a value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545056/writing-to-a-file-in-assembler/29545526#29545526

Comment: Also you don't clean up the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) convention, you should push the arguments in reverse order. So `f` should go first and `b` should go last. Also the stack should be cleaned up by the caller after calling `fwrite()`.

As noted in the comments, `b` will be received as value, but we need to pass it to `fwrite()` as pointer. The pointer will be equal to the value of `ebp` + `12`.

This seems to work for me:

```
    .global writebyte
writebyte:
    //create new stack frame
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    //push the four arguments to stack (in reverse order)
    pushl   8(%ebp)
    pushl   $1
    pushl   $1

    //get pointer of "b" argument (%ebp+12) and move it to %eax
    leal    12(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %eax

    //call fwrite()
    call    fwrite

    //remove arguments from stack and pop %ebp
    leave

    ret
```

Comment: why do you use underscore in call and function name?

Comment: Because I used Windows to compile this example and GCC on Windows requires the symbol names to begin with underscore, and actually prepends underscores to all the C functions. You can see that if you disassemble a compiled object files. But anyway, on Linux the underscores shoudn't be required, so I'll edit the post to remove them.

Comment: Why do you `pusha`/`popa`?  You even comment the line with the fact that it's our callers problem if they're clobbered.  That would let you use `leave` for the epilogue instead of `add $16, %esp` / `pop %ebp`.  (And of course, the compiler wouldn't even bother making a stack frame, but [gcc is dumb and copies the char into a local](https://godbolt.org/g/1QJSgc), rather than passing the address of its location on the stack.  Also, gcc keeps the stack 16B-aligned for `fwrite()`.  This tends not to matter, since stdio functions don't spill SSE vectors to the stack.)

Comment: You are right, the `pusha`/`popa` are not neccessary at all. Perhaps I wasn't paying attention when I was writing this. I'll edit the post to remove them. And it's interesting to see how GCC behaves.